# How to Calculate sum of numbers in a single textbox each time the button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I am currently working with asp.net vb code. I am trying to add numbers together each time a calculate button is cleared. I currently have a single textbox that I use to enter messages sent in a payroll application. I want to calculate the sum of the numbers each time the calculate button is clicked. I only have the one textbox. So the user will be entering the messages into THE SAME TEXTBOX and each time a new number is entered it will be added together.

I've tried `tbTotalMessages += messages` to try and add them(I assumed that's how you do it cuz that's what was explained in class but I think I misunderstood) because all that does is add the same number so if i put "23" then each time the button is clicked it goes "23232323"

This is the code I have for the calculate button I also have a pieceworkWorker class

```
 Dim inputName As String = tbWorkersName.Text
 Dim inputMessages As String = tbMessagesSent.Text
 Dim messages As Integer = 0
 Dim errorMessage As String = ""
 Dim overallMessages As Integer = 0

        If radioButtonList.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            Dim newWorker As PieceworkWorker

            If inputName.Trim = "" Then
                errorMessage += "Please enter a valid name"
            End If

            If Not (Integer.TryParse(inputMessages, messages)) AndAlso messages > -1 Then
                If errorMessage <> "" Then
                    errorMessage += Environment.NewLine
                End If

                errorMessage += "Please enter a valid number of text messages sent"
            End If

            If errorMessage <> "" Then
                Response.Write(errorMessage)
            Else
                newWorker = New PieceworkWorker(inputName, messages)
                newWorker.FindPay()
                tbLastWorkerPay.Text = newWorker.CalculatedPay.ToString()

            End If
        ElseIf radioButtonList.SelectedValue = 1 Then
            Dim newWorker As SeniorWorker

            If inputName.Trim = "" Then
                errorMessage += "Please enter a valid name"
            End If

            If Not (Integer.TryParse(inputMessages, messages)) AndAlso messages > -1 Then
                If errorMessage <> "" Then
                    errorMessage += Environment.NewLine
                End If

                errorMessage += "Please enter a valid number of text messages sent"
            End If

            If errorMessage <> "" Then
                Response.Write(errorMessage)
            Else
                newWorker = New SeniorWorker(inputName, messages)
                newWorker.FindPay()
                tbLastWorkerPay.Text = newWorker.CalculatedPay.ToString()
            End If
        End If

        tbNumberOfWorkers.Text = Val(tbNumberOfWorkers.Text) + 1.ToString()
        tbTotalMessages.Text += messages
```

Comment: Since it appears to be for a class, I won't give the answer but a hint instead: what type of data goes into a textbox? Once you figure that out, you'll be able to figure out how to add them. If that doesn't help, seeing that it's just concatenating 23 to the result each time is another hint.

Comment: Please show a bit more of your code. `tbTotalMessages += messages` tells me nothing. Is `tbTotalMessages` a variable that is a number type? Where does `messages` come from? What type is `messages`? You really need to work on your question skills. You don't have a single question without downvotes.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use Integer.Parse() and then += it. Textbox returns a string which means you are concatenating strings instead of adding numbers.

Comment: It doesnt let me do that it says conversion from type string to double is not valid

Comment: Damn, no iterator operations?